# Advance tickets for Pompeii

Tags: italy, archaeology, pompeii

Is it necessary to book tickets for entry to the archaeological site at Pompeii in advance (April 2022)? I find conflicting advice online.

If it is necessary, which (of the many, many) sites offering to sell tickets is the official one? The closest I got is http://pompeiisites.org/en/buy-tickets/ which is unencrypted and links to another site called TicketOne that my browser won't load without scary warnings.

Comment: By "necessary" do you mean that entry would be by advance ticket only, or that it's too busy to get in without a booking, or just to jump the queues? The site you linked seems to be the official one, but has no login or sales there. They do not say that advance tickets are needed, only that they are available. I have AV but get no warnings from TicketOne (which *is* encrypted). Note that in UK there are numerous sites that will pay the London Congestion Charge for you. They just charge you extra to do so.

Comment: Note that they have many [ticket outlets in Naples](https://www.ticketone.it/en/help/outlets/) zipcode 80.. and probably elsewhere too so you can buy them in advance without buying them online.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks – some travel blog sites say that tickets are mandatory, but they aren't always dated and it isn't clear that this is still the case. TicketOne's website seems to be triggering uBlock Origin warnings so I guess they just want to spy on me.

Comment: There is a detailed discussion about uBlock [here](https://appuals.com/fix-ublock-origin-has-prevented-the-following-page-from-loading/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site you mentioned ([this one](http://pompeiisites.org/en/)) is, in fact, the official website for the Pompeii archaeological park, and sadly it's not https...Consider that this site is useful for the info about the park, not for buying the tikets, and on the homepage you can find that:

> It is possible to buy the ticket online, through the TicketOne circuit (Official seller).  It is also possible to buy the ticket at the entrances, and at the self service ticket offices at Piazza Esedra and at Piazza Anfiteatro

So for enter the park the tikets are mandatory, you can buy them in advance in the self-service tiket offices, at the entrance (probably will cost you less money but more queue time) or online (that will cost you probably more money but less time).
The official seller of the tikets online is, as you mentioned, TiketOne (wich is one of the biggest websites for buy tikets online for events in italy) and it's https. Here is the link to the page about Pompeii: https://www.ticketone.it/en/artist/scavi-pompei/
There you will find two tikets: one for the "main tour" and one for Orione's house and garden (the cheaper one). For some weird reason there are three kind of tikets for the main tour, all for the same price, I couldn't find the difference between the three, I guess there is no difference.